# How to have an ongoing conversation with a Chatbot?

Tags: python, api, webhooks, chatbot

I have successfully implemented my chatbot on python that calls api.ai for an HTTP response then parsed the value basically getting the section that I want.
The issue is that I want an ongoing conversation, for example, let's assume I said hi, the bot says hello and the python code has run for the first time then I have to run it again asking how are you.

What I actually want is having a conversation with the bot no matter how many requests I may send and receive with one single run of the python code.

Comment: Are you using a webhook, or separate HTTP requests for fetching response ?

Comment: Seperate HTTP response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible structure of your program -

```
# Initialize your program, lots of code here, get token/id, setup other variables

def process_input(input_text):
    # clean input text
    # get response from web bot
    response = requests.get('url')
    # clean response and then print it/redirect it
    return response


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input()
        print(process_input(user_input))
        # also add some terminal conditions like if user types 'bye', break while loop and exit
```

Comment: I'll check it and accept the answer if it works well for me, Thanks. May you suggest a path or useful links to Webhook as i haven't used that before and interested to look into it.

Comment: In your normal HTTP calls, a new HTTP connection is created every time you make a new request. A webhook is a persistent connection and hence has lower overhead if you are doing multiple calls. This might help you - [webhooks](https://webhooks.pbworks.com/w/page/13385124/FrontPage) and [python websocket client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client)